# Xcode 7 Playground error: invalid context 0x0

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cgcontext, swift-playground

I am having this error in debug area, even when my playground file is empty:

> Sep 23 11:03:50  MyPlayground[68315] : CGContextSaveGState:
>   invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set
>   CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
>
> Sep 23 11:03:50  MyPlayground[68315] : CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the
>   backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental
>   variable.
>
> Sep 23 11:03:50  MyPlayground[68315] : CGContextRestoreGState:
>   invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the
>    backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental
>   variable.

I've seen answers suggesting modifying plist file. However, I am using `.playground` file, not an ordinary iOS project. There is no plist file inside the .playground. Any sollutions?

I am using `Xcode Version 7.0 (7A220)`.

Comment: Was that the .playground file created with previous versions of Xcode?

Comment: No, I have just created it in Xcode 7.

Comment: Report the bug to [Apple](http://radar.apple.com/). They already [know](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13683) about it, but it will speed up their processing of the bug.

Comment: Ok, I did. If they reply, I will let you all know.

Comment: there's an executable interpreter for terminal.just type 'swift' in a single line.I think it's better than playground.

Comment: Do you have an iPad simulator that exists in your regular iOS project? I know you're in a playground, but it's related.

Comment: @Mihado No I just started a new Playground, not a new Project.

Comment: @AntiMoron no code. As I already mentioned in my question, I open empty Playground file and this pops out.

Comment: I had the same issue. Look like Apple's bug.

Comment: @Rajesh Did you read the question? I was using Playground...

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be unrelated to your Xcode version as it happens to folks using 7.0 - 7.3. However, it *does* appear to be related to iOS version. This seems to be a 9.0 issue and upgrading your target to 9.1 or higher should fix it.

Apple reportedly knows about this bug and claimed it to be "fixed" as of 10/29/2015.

See [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13683).

Answer (score -1):

Try going to your app-info.plist. Check thre UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance and delete it.
This may help

Comment: As OP said multiple times, they are using a PLAYGROUND.

Comment: Based on the answers, I feel like maybe 10% of people read the actual question :-)